# How to suppress deprecation warning on annotation argument

Tags: java, deprecated

I compile javac 1.7.0_45 using the `-Xlint` option, the following code causes a deprecation warning.

```
@Deprecated
public class Bar {}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Foo {    
  @XmlElement(type = Bar.class)
  Object something;
}

>> Warning: Bar in mavenproject1 has been deprecated
```

I would have expected the `@SuppressWarnings` to prevent the warning message to be raised.

How to avoid this warning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling this is a bug / spec ambiguity that hasn't been addressed. If you search the [bug database](http://bugs.java.com/) there are plenty of these, such as: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7117383

Answer (score 0):

A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists. Compilers warn when a deprecated program element is used or overridden in non-deprecated code.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html